# ImportError for Django Piston handler that isn't tied to a model

Tags: django, importerror, django-piston

I have created a custom handler (`CustomHandler`) that isn't tied to a model in the ORM and I think it's rigged up correctly, but I'm getting an **`ImportError: cannot import CustomHandler`** when trying to import it into my `resources.py`. Here is my setup:

**custom_handlers.py**:

```
from piston.handler import BaseHandler

class CustomHandler(BaseHandler):
    allowed_methods = ('GET',)

    def read(self, request):
        return 'test'
```

**resources.py**:

```
from piston.resource import Resource
from piston.utils import rc
import simplejson as json
from api.authentication import DjangoAuthentication
from api.handlers import CustomHandler # ERROR THROWN HERE

auth = DjangoAuthentication(realm='...')

class JSONResource(Resource):
    def determine_emitter(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Default to the json emitter.
        """
        try:
            return kwargs['emitter_format']
        except KeyError:
            pass
        if 'format' in request.GET:
            return request.GET.get('format')
        return 'json'

    def form_validation_response(self, e):
        """
        Turns the error object into a serializable construct.
        """
        resp = rc.BAD_REQUEST
        json_errors = json.dumps(
            dict(
                (k, map(unicode, v))
                for (k, v) in e.form.errors.iteritems()
            )
        )
        resp.write(json_errors)
        return resp


custom_handler = JSONResource(CustomHandler, authentication=auth)
```

**urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url

from api.resources import custom_handler

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^things/$', custom_handler),
)
```

**UPDATE:** I've tried manually compiling the `py`s into `pyc`s with no luck. I also read this in [Piston's docs](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/FAQ#!why-does-piston-use-fields-from-previous-handlers):

> When you create a handler which is tied to a model, Piston will
>   automatically register it (via a metaclass.)

But I can't find anything in the docs about creating a handler that isn't tied to a model, specifically *how to register it*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add `from api.handlers.custom_handlers import CustomHandler` to `api/handlers/__init__.py`